# Total possible combinations of game won, lost, or tied by every team

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out every possible scenario of every team in a league either winning losing or tying given the amount teams and weeks left in the season.

For instance, the possible scenarios for one team and one week left in the season are 1-0-0, 0-1-0, and 0-0-1. If I were to add a week for that team, the scenarios would change to 1-0-0, 0-1-0, 0-0-1, 2-0-0, 1-1-0, 1-0-1, 0-2-0, 0-1-1, 0-0-2, resulting to 9 scenarios. I've figured out the formula to be to be $\frac{(w^3+6w^2+11w)}{6}$ for adding a number of weeks.

If the number of teams given 1 week were to be incremented, one team would have 1-0-0, 0-1-0, 0-0-1, totaling to 3 scenarios. Adding another team, 1-0-0 and 1-0-0, 1-0-0 and 0-1-0, 1-0-0 and 0-0-1, 0-1-0 and 1-0-0, 0-1-0 and 0-1-0, 0-1-0 and 0-0-1, 0-0-1 and 1-0-0, 0-0-1 and 0-1-0, 0-0-1 and 0-0-1, totaling to 9 scenarios. I've figured out the formula for adding a number of teams to be $3^t$.

My question is how to combine these 2 equations? Graphed out:

[image: table]

Comment: In your scenario, with two teams, it is possible for them both to win simultaneously?  Are they simply not playing eachother?

Comment: Do all teams have the same number of weeks to go?

Comment: You seem not to insist that each team play every week, because in the two week case you still allow only one game left.  Without considering the schedule, you miss correlations between teams.  For example, in the one week case, if A plays B they can't both win.

Comment: Also, "if i were to add a week... change to 1-0-0,...2-0-0,1-1-0", are the teams not necessarily going to play every week that is available?  In your example, with 2 weeks left you say it was possible for a 1-0-0 record and a 2-0-0 record?  The team could have played a single game over two weeks or two games over two weeks?

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand your concern. I'm writing a program and haven't gotten to which team plays which, so please ignore that fact, even if two teams remain. Also 1-0-0 means the team has played a single game over one week and 2-0-0 means the team has played two games over two weeks. Every week represents a game played.

Comment: So, with 2 weeks to go, will a team play 2 games? potentially 1 game? potentially no games?

Comment: They will play all of their games.

Comment: Question — long shot since this thread is like 7 years old — What if you wanted to figure out the minimum number of teams in a league that could finish with at least .500 record? For example — there are 12 teams in a league and they play 14 games, meaning you play only 3 of the teams twice. What’s the minimum number of teams that could finish with a winning or at least .500 record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not interested in the order in which the wins/losses/ties occur, and you're seemingly allowing the wins of one team to not influence at all the number of wins of another team (i.e., they are not playing against eachother), this degenerates for each team into the question of "how many ways can I put $w$ unlabled balls into $3$ labled urns."

To answer, use the stars and bars method: it becomes $\binom{w+3-1}{3-1} = \frac{(w+2)\cdot(w+1)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(w^2 + 3w + 2)$ number of ways.

If each team is again independent and not playing eachother and each team is distinguishable (i.e., all sequences are possible for every team and the teams are labeled), then raise the previous answer to the power of $t$ for a final total of $(\frac{1}{2}(w^2 + 3w + 2))^t$

---

If you allow each team to play potentially fewer than the total number of weeks left number of games, you could view this as instead of W-L-T, as being W-L-T-N  where the final number is null/didn't play.  Again, by stars and bars method it becomes now $\binom{w+4-1}{4-1} = \frac{(w+3)(w+2)(w+1)}{6} = \frac{1}{6} (w^3 + 6w^2 + 11w+6)$.

Then with a set number of distinguishable teams each with each possibility it is $(\frac{(w+3)(w+2)(w+1)}{6})^t$

---

If you insist that each team in question will play minimum of one game, you subtract the possibility of getting a 0-0-0 (-w) record (only one way it could have happened), so you can subtract 1 from the amount of ways for each team. $\frac{1}{6} (w^3 + 6w^2 + 11w+6) - 1 = \frac{1}{6} (w^3 + 6w^2 + 11w)$

Comment: Thanks! Your first solution was the one I was looking for. Given two teams with one week remaining, the formula gives 9 scenarios. 2 teams and 2 weeks remaining gives 36 scenarios. 2 teams and 3 weeks remaining gives 100 scenarios. 9+36+100 = 145 total scenarios given 3 full weeks.

Answer (score 0):

If one team has $N(w)$ options for a set number of weeks, then $t$ teams has $N(w)^t$ options, so overall there are $$\sum_w (N(w))^t$$ options.
$N(w)=(w+1)(w+2)/2$, so 
$$\sum_{w=1}^W \left(\frac{w^2+3w+2}2\right)^t$$

Comment: If different teams may have different numbers of games left, then it becomes $((w^3+6w^2+11w)/6)^t$ instead.